# Finding the limit of $\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How would one find the limit of the following.

as $n\rightarrow\infty$

$$\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}}$$

I did the following

$$\frac{3\cdot 3^m}{1/4 \cdot 4^m}$$

$$\frac{3}{\frac{1}{4}}\ \frac{3^m}{4^m}$$

The limit if zero.

Another one I did is

$$\frac{2^{3n-1}}{7^{n+2}}$$

I did the following

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{49}\ \frac{8^n}{7^n}$$

which means n approach infinity

But I am not sure if I did this correctly the numbers I got on the let side.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: I see because if you do 2^-1 you would get 1/2

Comment: +1 for showing all your work and checking for confirmation on the bits you were unsure of - this is exactly how to pose a homework(ish) question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n}\cdot 3}{4^{n}\cdot 4^{-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3^{n}\cdot 3\cdot 4}{4^{n}}=12\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{3}{4})^{n}$=$12\cdot 0$=$0$, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{3}{4})^{n}=0$.

Your answer is correct.

and the another

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n-1}}{7^{n+2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n}\cdot 2^{-1}}{7^{n}\cdot 7^{2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2^{3n}}{7^{n}\cdot 7^2\cdot 2}=\frac{1}{98}\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{8}{7})^{n}$=$\infty$, because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{8}{7})^{n}=\infty$.